# Properties of regular bipartite graphs

Tags: graph-theory

I am often asked to prove properties of regular bipartite graphs, and beyond the two parts having equal size nothing seems obvious. Are these graphs more intuitive than they first seem?

In particular, right now I can't work out why an r-regular bipartite graph is r-edge-colourable.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

A $r$-regular bipartite graph has not only two parts of equal size, but by Hall's Marriage Theorem, it has a perfect matching. Hence, you can take out that perfect matching, and the graph will become regular bipartite. Keep doing this, we will get a partition of $r$ independent classes of the edges, that is the $r$-edge-colouring we want.

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce this problem (through induction on $r$) to looking for a perfect matching that covers all the nodes.

Thanks to the [Hall's marriage theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall%27s_marriage_theorem), you can prove there's one by verifying the condition that for every subset $S$ of the nodes on the left, the number of nodes on the right connected to $S$ is greater or equal to the cardinality of $S$, and that's easy to see thanks to the regularity of the graph.